# enum fields displaying STRING instead of ORDINAL

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, enums

I am currently using Hibernate in a Spring MVC design app that takes in data and stores it into a MySQL DB. I have a mixture of models and enums mapped with eachother. Everything works well and the data, being stored into the DB, is correct (it's storing the enum ORDINAL values).

However, when I output the results using the findAll() method from the CrudRepository, the results shows the correct enum values but in its STRING form instead of its ORDINAL form. Any ideas on what I could implement or is this how things are?

Below is a small snippet of code to show what I have so far:

The Enum (labeled "Cars"):

```
FORD, 
TOYOTA, 
CHEVY
```

A POJO snippet (labeled "Dealership"):

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Cars carType;
//getters and setters
```

The DAO (labeled "DealershipDAO"):

```
public interface DealershipDao extends CrudRepository<Dealership, Integer> {
}
```

The controller:

```
@Autowired
private DealershipDao dao;

@RequestMapping(value="/dataLoad")
public String dataLoad() {
    Dealership dealer = new Dealership();
    dealer.setCarType(Cars.FORD);


    dao.save(dealer);

    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/findEverything", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Dealership> findAll() {
    return dao.findAll();
}
```

Now, if I use  a MySQL editor to view the data, the Dealership table does show the enum ORDINAL value for FORD (after I call the /dataLoad request). But when I call the /findEverything request, it displays the String, FORD, and not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How an enum is transformed to JSON by Jackson has nothing to do with JPA. You need to tell Jackson how to serialize your enum. For example using the [JsonFormat annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html)